# IdentityServer4 logout from external provider like Google

Tags: react-native, asp.net-identity, expo, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using IdentityServer4 with Asp.Net Core Identity. In Identity Server I enabled GOOGLE as external provider. I'm able to LOGIN with GOOGLE. The first time I try to LOG IN with GOOGLE the Identity Server shows to me the pages of the GOOGLE where I can choose the account or insert my credentials.

When I LOGOUT I receive the message that I'm logged out but when I try to LOGIN again with GOOGLE  I'm directly logged in without to enter my credentials and if I have more than 1 GOOGLE account I'm not able to choose a different one.

This happens both if I connect directly to the server from the Login screen and if I do it via AuthRequest in Expo native app calling endsession endpoint with `id_token_hint` enhanced.

Why? I'm getting crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://myIdentityServerEndSessionEndpoint", "exp://myReactNativeApp");
```